# Hive 1.x loses tables

Tags: hive

I restarted by hadoop dfs and yarn processes and now hive doesn't see any tables.

However, if I look in hdfs /user/hive, I see the tables there.

Hive's show tables, however shows no tables.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive needs to be started in the same directory.